# Internet drops out periodically and sometimes comes back

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a HP Elitebook.  While on Wifi (hasn't happened on ethernet), my internet drops out seemingly randomly.  Sometimes I'll have internet for days before it happens,  sometimes it happens every few minutes.

If I leave a ping open, I'll have normal responses.  When the internet drops, I get these error messages:

```
From 192.168.0.8 icmp_seq=71 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I wait, sometimes the internet comes back on its own.  If I get impatient, running this command fixes it until the next time it drops out.

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Any idea what the problem could be?  Let me know if you want to see any sort of diagnostics (and how to preform said diagnostics).

Comment: Other devices on my wifi work just fine.  Though no other device is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Here's a ping readout of a time where my internet stopped then started working again.  After icmp_seq 4609 I had a 10-15 second pause before the next message.  Also not that the "Destination Host Unreachable" icmp_seq values are out of order.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tfHAxwk.png

Comment: How far away is your wireless access point to your laptop? If you run an ethernet cable, do you have any issues? Do you live in an area with many wireless networks? Restarting NetworkManager is basically reconnecting to the network, so it seems your card may be having issues, or there are signal issues. You can test the signal strength using a smartphone and a wifi app.